# Multisite Equivalent of `register_setting`?

Tags: multisite, options, settings-api

Working on converting a custom plugin to run in multisite.  I want the settings to apply globally, not per-site.  I've converted all of the `get_option` calls to `get_site_option` and the equivalent for `set_option`.

But, how do you register a setting in the UX that saves globally to sitemeta instead of options?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite similar to regular options pages, you just need to use `network_admin_menu` hook instead of `admin_menu`.

As for `register_settings()` function, as I know, there is no equivalent yet. So, we have to work with HTML when creating options pages.

You can check this tut https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress-multisite/options-pages.html